# Maven enforcer append in children

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am using the maven enforcer plugin. Given I have a parent and child `pom.xml`, I would like that the elements in the `exclusions` and `inclusions` tags are appended rather than overridden. I have tried using `combine.children="append"` for this and it works but I am ending up with an extra `configuration` tag. Am I using `combine.children` incorrectly and/or how can I avoid the extra `configuration` tag? See the example below:

In parent `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <bannedDependencies>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>org.apache.maven</exclude>
                    <exclude>org.apache.maven:badArtifact</exclude>
                    <exclude>*:badArtifact</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                  <includes>
                    <!--only 1.0 of badArtifact is allowed-->
                    <include>org.apache.maven:badArtifact:1.0</include>
                  </includes>
                </bannedDependencies>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

In child `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <bannedDependencies>
              <includes combine.children="append">
                <include>org.apache.maven:otherArtifact:2.0</include>
              </includes>
            </bannedDependencies>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Expected effective POM:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <bannedDependencies>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>org.apache.maven</exclude>
                    <exclude>org.apache.maven:badArtifact</exclude>
                    <exclude>*:badArtifact</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                  <includes>
                    <!--only 1.0 of badArtifact is allowed-->
                    <include>org.apache.maven:badArtifact:1.0</include>
                    <include>org.apache.maven:otherArtifact:2.0</include>
                  </includes>
                </bannedDependencies>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Actual effective POM:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <bannedDependencies>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>org.apache.maven</exclude>
                    <exclude>org.apache.maven:badArtifact</exclude>
                    <exclude>*:badArtifact</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                  <includes combine.children="append>
                    <!--only 1.0 of badArtifact is allowed-->
                    <include>org.apache.maven:badArtifact:1.0</include>
                    <include>org.apache.maven:otherArtifact:2.0</include>
                  </includes>
                </bannedDependencies>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <bannedDependencies>
              <includes combine.children="append">
                <include>org.apache.maven:otherArtifact:2.0</include>
              </includes>
            </bannedDependencies>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: Well that is expected. The parent POM uses an execution `<configuration>` element while child POM uses the global configuration (not under any execution). In fact, I think your `combine.children="append"` has no effect here. You're not overriding the same configuration element.

Comment: If I do not use the append the effective pom will only contain `<include>org.apache.maven:otherArtifact:2.0</include>`. Therefore it does have an effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to get the expected merged configuration you should then have in your child module the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <bannedDependencies>
                        <includes>
                            <include>org.apache.maven:badArtifact:2.0</include>
                        </includes>
                    </bannedDependencies>
                </rules>
                <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

That is, reusing the same execution `id` value in order to point (override/merge) the same execution with additional configuration.

Then the merged effective pom will be as following:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <bannedDependencies>
                        <includes combine.children="append">
                            <include>org.apache.maven:badArtifact:1.0</include>
                            <include>org.apache.maven:badArtifact:2.0</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>org.apache.maven</exclude>
                            <exclude>org.apache.maven:badArtifact</exclude>
                            <exclude>*:badArtifact</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </bannedDependencies>
                </rules>
                <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Hence, no need to use it: the default merging behavior will suit your needs.

---

One important note about the usage of `combine.*` attributes, from [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins)

> Note that these attributes only apply to the configuration element they are declared on, and are not propagated to nested elements. That is if the content of an item element from the child POM was a complex structure instead of text, its sub-elements would still be subject to the default merge strategy unless they were themselves marked with attributes.